# Conditions for continuity of component functions of a continuous composite functions

Tags: continuity

Let $f: \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$ and $g:\mathcal Y \to \mathcal Z$ be maps such that $g \circ f$ is continuous. Then under what condition we can say-(1) $f$ is continuous., (2)-$g$ is continuous?

Comment: I don't think any condition can be said about $f$. Let $g$ be a constant function, then $g \circ f$ is trivially continuous.

Comment: I'd asked about dependency of continuity of f and g on the continuity of gof.

Comment: But you have already assumed g as continuous function.